# Can't update store view specific labels of order statuses

Tags: magento2, magento2.1

I can't update the store view-specific labels of order statuses in Magento 2.1.7.

Once I enter any status label for the store view, it's coming up blank, not saved in the db.

I have tried all solutions; I've even checked in all versions of Magento 2.x.

How can I do this?

Comment: Are you trying to use your own dictionary for labels?

Comment: No, I am using by default , saving from admin for store view labels,I have found the bug in magento 2. there is issue with the update and save function. So i have saved label directly in database and working fine.